Problem setting up Baserow with SSL on Oracle VPS
I installed Baserow with this script and Baserow worked successfully. I also installed Caddy for automatic SSL and it also worked.
docker run   -d   --name baserow   -e BASEROW_PUBLIC_URL=http://89.168.51.27:8080   -v baserow_data:/baserow/data   -p 8080:80   -p 442:443   --restart unless-stopped   baserow/baserow:1.24.2

Base row setup:

This is my CaddyFile.
baserow.valetclub.ma {
        reverse_proxy http://89.168.51.27:8080
}


When I access with my domain name it shows me Site not found .
Base row public view:

